# EFCore access mysql cannot use Distinct() in sub query？

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, distinct, group

MySql8.0
.net7
EF7

My Entity

```
public class Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string BlogName { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
var rt = _context
    .Authors
    .Select(a => new
    {
        a.ID,
        //BlogNames = a.Blogs.Select(b => b.BlogName).Distinct(),//also
        BlogNames = a.Blogs.GroupBy(b => b.BlogName).Select(b => b.Key)
    });
var lst = rt.ToList();
```

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulgmq.jpg)

Error Message:

> System.InvalidOperationException:“The LINQ expression 'OUTER APPLY
> (
> SELECT b.BlogName
> FROM Blogs AS b
> WHERE a.ID == b.AuthorID
> GROUP BY b.BlogName
> ) AS t' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.”

But when i change mysql to sql server,it's running,why?

I want run this code to get a list that contains the author whith unique blog names.
when i use same code with sql server it's good.

Comment: Here you have Database engine limitation. MySql do not support OUTER APPLY JOIN, which is required for such construction. Not sure, but try `a.Blogs.Select(b => b.BlogName).ToList().Distinct()`

Comment: Thanks,but my second level table have too many records,ToList() will generate too much network traffic.

Comment: Actulally not too much, only duplicates and you have no so many choices.